# how to stop if statements carrying on after you want it to end

Tags: python, if-statement

HI all sorry new to all this and learning -

Im writing this

```
print('''
*******************************************************************************
          |                   |                  |                     |
 _________|________________.=""_;=.______________|_____________________|_______
|                   |  ,-"_,=""     `"=.|                  |
|___________________|__"=._o`"-._        `"=.______________|___________________
          |                `"=._o`"=._      _`"=._                     |
 _________|_____________________:=._o "=._."_.-="'"=.__________________|_______
|                   |    __.--" , ; `"=._o." ,-"""-._ ".   |
|___________________|_._"  ,. .` ` `` ,  `"-._"-._   ". '__|___________________
          |           |o`"=._` , "` `; .". ,  "-._"-._; ;              |
 _________|___________| ;`-.o`"=._; ." ` '`."\` . "-._ /_______________|_______
|                   | |o;    `"-.o`"=._``  '` " ,__.--o;   |
|___________________|_| ;     (#) `-.o `"=.`_.--"_o.-; ;___|___________________
____/______/______/___|o;._    "      `".o|o_.--"    ;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/_"=._o--._        ; | ;        ; ;/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/__"=._o--._   ;o|o;     _._;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/____"=._o._; | ;_.--"o.--"_/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/______/_____"=.o|o_.--""___/______/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/_____ /
*******************************************************************************
''')
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.") 

#https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Treasure%20Island%20Conditional.drawio#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1oDe4ehjWZipYRsVfeAx2HyB7LCQ8_Fvi%26export%3Ddownload

#Write your code below this line 


name = (input("What is your Name ? "))
print (f"Welcome {name} to the Treasure Island game. Lets get started!")

step1 = input(" Do you pick left or right? ")

if step1.lower() == ("left"):
  print ("congratulations you have avoid the pit of snakes! and moved to your next choice!")
elif step1 == ("right"):
  
  print ("""

         OH no you fell into a pit full of SNAKES!

       
    --..,_                     _,.--.
       `'.'.                .'`__ o  `;__.      
          '.'.            .'.'`  '---'`  `
            '.`'--....--'`.'
              `'--....--'`



""")


  

step2 = (input("You come up to a lake do you wait or do you swim? "))
```

The problem Im having is if someone picks the right option it should just say you fell in with a pit of snakes (with the ascii art)

I want it either to end there or ideally would like to learn how to loop it so I can ask the user if they want to restart and then start from the beginning.

but whats happening atm is if someone picks right it gives them the message with the art but then asks them the next question >

```
step2 = (input("You come up to a lake do you wait or do you swim? "))
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Try adding some `while` loops and `breaks`. Because your question is closed, I can't answer it nicely, but here is a screen shot of the code I made for you to give it a go [game code](https://i.imgur.com/qaKTsfv.png)